# Allow user type only text in input field

Tags: javascript, html

I need a validator that allows user type only `text` `number` and `@`

when user types other than these charter like `#, $, % ,^ , &, *, (,`
these charter should not type in input field is there any way to block other than allowed charter inside input field

Comment: might be worth looking up Regex

Comment: Server or clientsided? And it looks like you want to validate an E-Mail string?

Comment: Use JS with regex like /[a-zA-ZA]+/ and call replace / subString to remove the added, unwanted character.

Comment: @Steini in client side if user type `#` these charter should not get typed in input box

Comment: What do you mean by “text”? In many definitions, “text” means any characters. You seem to mean letters instead, but exactly which? Is “Brontë” text? What about “Þor” and “Путин”?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably looking for regex. 
Try testing the string on keyUp event on the below regexp:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9@]+$
```

**CODE:**

```js
// This will be triggered everytime a user types anything
// in the input field with id as input-field
$("#input-field").keyup(function(e) {
  // Our regex
  // a-z => allow all lowercase alphabets
  // A-Z => allow all uppercase alphabets
  // 0-9 => allow all numbers
  // @ => allow @ symbol
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9@]+$/;
  // This is will test the value against the regex
  // Will return True if regex satisfied
  if (regex.test(this.value) !== true)
  //alert if not true
  //alert("Invalid Input");

  // You can replace the invalid characters by:
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@]+/, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-field" />
```

**UPDATE:**

Without jquery:

```js
function validate() {
  var element = document.getElementById('input-field');
  element.value = element.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@]+/, '');
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field" onkeyup="validate();" />
```

Comment: can you make a full script

Comment: is there a way to work without jquery

Comment: How could you allow spaces in the input?

Comment: @demonhunter24 You can use `\s` for spaces in the regex

Answer (score 1):

You may try with RegEx

```js
$(function() {//<-- wrapped here
  $('.restrict').on('input', function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@]/g, ''); //<-- replace all other than given set of values
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='restrict'>
```

**EDIT**

With pure js

```js
var restrict = function(tb) {
  tb.value = tb.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@]/g, '');
};
```

```html
<input type='text' onpaste="restrict(this);" onkeypress="restrict(this);" onkeyup="restrict(this);">
<input type='text' onpaste="restrict(this);" onkeypress="restrict(this);" onkeyup="restrict(this);">
```

Comment: i tried your code its not working

Comment: `<input id="textinput" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Sanoj Lawrence" class="form-control input-md">`thats input field`$('#textinput').on('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@]/g, '');
});`

Comment: @sanojoverflow, did it worked for you here? did you wrapped your code inside $(document).ready(function(){/* to do here */}) or $(function(){/* to do here */})?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){$("#textinput").on('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@]/g, '');
});}) ;` this is how am using now and not working

Comment: @sanojoverflow, any errors on web browser console? Press F12 to see it.

Comment: It works since am using older version of jquery now it works

Comment: how do i work above script without support of `jquery` is there any method because i don't use `jquery` in my page so is there any way to skip jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for javascript validation-

```
function validate(inputtxt)
{
 var letterNumber = /^[0-9a-zA-Z@]+$/;
 if((inputtxt.value.match(letterNumber)) 
  {
   return true;
  }
else
  { 
   alert("message"); 
   return false; 
  }
  }
```

and try to put this line in your html code, replace the name of your form or input field-

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate(document.form.text)" />
```

Comment: i don't want to show alert message simple user cant enter those charte in field